# How to get data from Json in android

Tags: java, android

My json like this:

```
{"Results":
"orderList":[{
    "Orderid":"5","Amount":"250.00","Date":"2016-04-21 08:27:43.0","
        Items":["North Indian Veg-1","North Indian NonVeg-1","South Indian Veg-1","South Indian Non Veg-1"]}]}
```

I know how to get "Orderid","Amount","Date" from "orderList". But, I want to get Items also. How to get Items from above json.

Code here:

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(response));
     JSONArray result = obj.getJSONArray("Results");

     if(result!=null&&result.length()>0){
         for(int i = 0;i<result.length();i++){
             JSONObject jsonResultObject = result.getJSONObject(i);
             JSONArray order = jsonResultObject.getJSONArray("orderList");

             if((order!=null && order.length()>0)){
                 for(int k=0;k<order.length();k++){
                    JSONObject jsonOrder = order.getJSONObject(k);
                    String orderId = jsonOrder.getString("Orderid").toString();
                    String amount = jsonOrder.getString("Amount").toString();
                    String date = jsonOrder.getString("Date").toString();
                  }
               }
           }
}
```

Please anyone help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: json is not valid. paste your json here for validation and formatting: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a right json structure :when you create json structure then varied on jsonlint.com web site or when create json structure use this web site.

```
 {
"orderList": [{
    "Orderid": "",
    "Amount": "250.00",
    "Date": "2016-04-21 08:27:43.0",
    "Item": {
        "North Indian Veg": "",
        "North Indian NonVeg": "",
        "South Indian Veg": "",
        "South Indian Non Veg": ""
    }
}]
```

}

Answer (score -1):

get your items data using this

```
String item1 = getjsonObj("Results").getJsonArray("orderList").getJsonArray("Items").getstring(0);

String item2 = getjsonObj("Results").getJsonArray("orderList").getJsonArray("Items").getstring(1);
```

and do it till the Item array length in a for loop